# How to set multi line Large title in navigation bar? ( New feature of iOS 11)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar, large-title

I am in process of adding large title in navigation bar in one of the application. The issue is title is little long so I will require to add two lines in large title. How can I add **large title** with two lines in navigation bar?

**This is not about default navigation bar title! This is about large title which is introduced in iOS 11**. So make sure you add suggestions by considering large title. Thanks

<kbd>[image: Title text truncated with 3 dots in the navigation bar]</kbd>

Comment: Put a label in a UIView set number of lines as 0 and then add the view as Navigation bar's  TitleView. Problem solved

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Does this behave properly (like the original title label) with varying navigation bar items: Length of back button label, left/right bar items?

Comment: @meaning-matters : You can always specify the frame for titleView if it overlaps with left/right bar button items :)

Comment: Try that in large title ( new feature of iOS 11 if you are now aware!)

Comment: @JigarThakkar This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907710/5638630

Answer (score 15):

Get a navigation item subviews and locate UILabel from it.

Try this and see:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

self.title = "This is multiline title for navigation bar"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [                     
                                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                                NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
                                ]

for navItem in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
     for itemSubView in navItem.subviews { 
         if let largeLabel = itemSubView as? UILabel {
             largeLabel.text = self.title
             largeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
             largeLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
         }
     }
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: @Krunal I've used the for loop that you've provided to find the large title label subview, but when I try customizing the attributedTitle of that label nothing shows up

Comment: @Krunal Yup I get the `UILabel` and settings text and other properties work, but not `attributedTitle`, using iPhone 8 Plus iOS 11.2

Comment: I agree with Jigar. I have a back button and this isn't working. It works when I swipe the page from the left side a bit (as if to go back) but then let it bounce back into place.

Comment: Adding this lines improves behavior on the larges titles when you have backbutton:

`largeLabel.sizeToFit()
navigationBar.frame.size.height =  50 + largeLabel.frame.height`

Comment: does anybody faced the issue when you navigate to a next page where the title is small and bar collapse and when you come back your title switched back to one line followed by .....

Comment: i tried the same in Xcode12.5. It doesnt work

Answer (score 15):

Based in @krunal answer, this is working for me:

```
extension UIViewController {

func setupNavigationMultilineTitle() {
    guard let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }
    for sview in navigationBar.subviews {
        for ssview in sview.subviews {
            guard let label = ssview as? UILabel else { break }
            if label.text == self.title {
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                label.sizeToFit()
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    navigationBar.frame.size.height = 57 + label.frame.height
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "This is a multiline title"
    setupNavigationMultilineTitle()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    setupNavigationMultilineTitle()
}
```

And for setting font and color on the large title:

```
navigation.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: .red, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)]
```

Comment: This works really well. I do notice a slight gap in the animation when I try this code. It may be that the constant `57` is not enough here.

Comment: Yes, i fix it changing the value depending on the device:

let offset: CGFloat = UIDevice.current.iPhone5 ? 53 : 57

Comment: This solution does not seems to work in iOS 13 with Xcode 11.

Comment: Seems like in iOS 13 the navigationBar subview hierarchy is more complex so I'm using a recursive function to change all UILabels. This does work for me with the standard size title, but not the large title, though... still debugging this.

Comment: Not working on iOS 16

Answer (score 4):

The linebreak solution seems to be problematic when there's a back button. So instead of breaking lines, I made the label auto adjust font.

```
func setupLargeTitleAutoAdjustFont() {
    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {
        return
    }
    // recursively find the label
    func findLabel(in view: UIView) -> UILabel? {
        if view.subviews.count > 0 {
            for subview in view.subviews {
                if let label = findLabel(in: subview) {
                    return label
                }
            }
        }
        return view as? UILabel
    }

    if let label = findLabel(in: navigationBar) {
        if label.text == self.title {
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7
        }
    }
}
```

Then it needs to be called in viewDidLayoutSubviews() to make sure the label can be found, and we only need to call it once:

```
private lazy var setupLargeTitleLabelOnce: Void = {[unowned self] in
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.setupLargeTitleAutoAdjustFont()
    }
}()

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let _ = setupLargeTitleLabelOnce
}
```

If there's any navigationController pop event back to this controller, we need to call it again in viewDidAppear(). I haven't found a better solution for this - there's a small glitch of label font changing when coming back from a pop event:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        setupLargeTitleAutoAdjustFont()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for **Title Lable** Not Large Title, then below code is working.

**Swift 5.X**

```
func setMultilineNavigationBar(topText:  String, bottomText : String) {
     let topTxt = NSLocalizedString(topText, comment: "")
     let bottomTxt = NSLocalizedString(bottomText, comment: "")
        
     let titleParameters = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                               NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)]
     let subtitleParameters = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                                  NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)]
        
     let title:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: topTxt, attributes: titleParameters)
     let subtitle:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: bottomTxt, attributes: subtitleParameters)
        
     title.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
     title.append(subtitle)
        
     let size = title.size()
        
     let width = size.width
     guard let height = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height else {return}
        
      let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
      titleLabel.attributedText = title
      titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
      titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
      self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel 
    }
```

Comment: This just puts a multi-line label in the default title view. The question is how to have a multi-line *large* title view.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit 7/13: I notice that this solution is not support scrollView, so now I'm in research)

I found a perfect solution **on Swift5**

but sorry for my poor English because I'm JapaneseStudent.

[In case of 2 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjEdr.png) [In case of 3 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt2hh.png)

At first, set navigation settings for largeTitle normally in `viewDidLoad`

```
//Set largeTitle
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (fontSize + margin) * numberOfLines)]//ex) fontSize=26, margin=5, numberOfLines=2
        
//Set title
title = "multiple large\ntitle is working!"
```

It is most important point of this solution that font-size at `largeTitleTextAttributes` equals actual font-size(+margin) multiplied by number of lines.

[Description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RPCD.png)

Because, default specification of navigationBar attributes may be able to  display **only 1 line** largeTitle.

Although, somehow, I did notice that in case of label-settings(the label which subview of subview of navigationBar) on direct, **it can display any number of lines in 1 line of in case of navigationBar attributes**.

So, we should do set big font in navigationbar attributes, and set small font in the label(subview of subview of navigationBar), and take into consideration the margins.

Do label settings direct in `viewDidAppear` like this:

```
//Find label
navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach({ subview in
        subview.subviews.forEach { subsubview in
        guard let label: UILabel = subsubview as? UILabel else { return }
        //Label settings on direct.
        label.text = title
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.sizeToFit()
    }
})
```

Therefore, in short, the solution at minimum code is given like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let fontSize: CGFloat = 26, margin: CGFloat = 5
    private let numberOfLines: CGFloat = 2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpNavigation()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        setMultipleLargeTitle()
    }
    private func setUpNavigation() {
        //Set largeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (fontSize + margin) * numberOfLines)]
        
        //Set title
        title = "multiple large\ntitle is working!"
    }
    private func setMultipleLargeTitle() {
        //Find label
        navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach({ subview in
            subview.subviews.forEach { subsubview in
                guard let label: UILabel = subsubview as? UILabel else { return }
                //Label settings on direct.
                label.text = title
                label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                label.sizeToFit()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

thank you for reading :)

Comment: I couldnt make it work, my Title just got Bigger (because of the font size) instead of separating into multiple lines, are you missing some implementation, or any news on your investigation on scrollview??

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** : Multi line even though the sentence is only short

```
title = "You're \nWelcome"

for navItem in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
     for itemSubView in navItem.subviews { 
         if let largeLabel = itemSubView as? UILabel {
             largeLabel.text = self.title
             largeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
             largeLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
         }
     }
}
```

[image: Proof]

Comment: this doesn't work if you have buttons, for me it just cuts the second part out, and it's not there

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using SwiftUI HostingView either.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5** This UIViewController extension helped me. Scenario that I have is mixed with enabling and disabling large titles <s>so FIRST ENABLE large title and then call this method</s>. Call it in viewDidLoad, I have found bug with peeking back with swipe and then releasing touch, for some reason current navigation title become previous navigation title

```
    extension UIViewController {

/// Sets two lines for navigation title if needed
/// - Parameter animated: used for changing titles on one controller,in that case animation is off
func multilineNavTitle(_ animated:Bool = true) {
    
    if animated {
        // setting initial state for animation of title to look more native
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: .screenWidth/2, y: 0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
    }
    
    //Checks if two lines is needed
    if self.navigationItem.title?.forTwoLines() ?? false {
        
        // enabling multiline
        navigationItem.setValue(true,
                                forKey: "__largeTitleTwoLineMode")
    } else {
        
        // disabling multiline
        navigationItem.setValue(false,
                                forKey: "__largeTitleTwoLineMode")
    }
    
    // laying out title without animation
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutSubviews()
        self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    if animated {
        //animating title
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1
        }
    }

}


}


fileprivate extension String {

/// Checks if navigation title is wider than label frame
/// - Returns: `TRUE` if title cannot fit in one line of navigation title label
func forTwoLines() -> Bool {
    
    let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: SomeFont]
    let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
    return size.width > CGFloat.screenWidth - 40 //in my case
    
}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a custom navigation controller. Rest will be handled by the OS itself

```
class MyNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.delegate = self 
    }

}

extension MyNavigationViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPush item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        item.setValuesForKeys([
            "__largeTitleTwoLineMode": true
        ])
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```swift
viewController.navigationItem
    .setValuesForKeys(["__largeTitleTwoLineMode": true])
```

> WARNING: This method does not work on older OS versions

Comment: This seems to break pull-to-refresh, at least in iOS 16.1.