# automatically adjust the text size of a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically adjust the size of a text according to the length of the words ? 
To prevent the text from being trimmed.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;
 self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Interface",nil);
```

[image]

Comment: Uhh how about line breaks?

Comment: I update the topic with my code !! I am talking about the navigation title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multi line Large title in navigation bar? ( New feature of iOS 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901318/how-to-set-multi-line-large-title-in-navigation-bar-new-feature-of-ios-11)